# Handle missing time series data with .defined() in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time-series

The following code produces a time series for each array in `values`.

```js
'use strict';
var times = [new Date(1511589600000),new Date(1511589660000),new Date(1511589720000),new Date(1511589780000),new Date(1511589840000),new Date(1511589900000),new Date(1511589960000),new Date(1511590020000),new Date(1511590080000),new Date(1511590140000),new Date(1511590200000),new Date(1511590260000),new Date(1511590320000),new Date(1511590380000),new Date(1511590440000),new Date(1511590500000),new Date(1511590560000),new Date(1511590620000),new Date(1511590680000),new Date(1511590740000),new Date(1511590800000),new Date(1511590860000),new Date(1511590920000),new Date(1511590980000),new Date(1511591040000),new Date(1511591100000),new Date(1511591160000),new Date(1511591220000),new Date(1511591280000),new Date(1511591340000),new Date(1511591400000),new Date(1511591460000),new Date(1511591520000),new Date(1511591580000),new Date(1511591640000),new Date(1511591700000),new Date(1511591760000),new Date(1511591820000),new Date(1511591880000),new Date(1511591940000),new Date(1511592000000),new Date(1511592060000),new Date(1511592120000),new Date(1511592180000),new Date(1511592240000),new Date(1511592300000),new Date(1511592360000),new Date(1511592420000),new Date(1511592480000),new Date(1511592540000),new Date(1511592600000),new Date(1511592660000),new Date(1511592720000),new Date(1511592780000),new Date(1511592840000),new Date(1511592900000),new Date(1511592960000),new Date(1511593020000),new Date(1511593080000),new Date(1511593140000),new Date(1511593200000)];
var values = [[25.44,25.44,25.44,25.44,25.44,25.44,25.752,26.064,26.376,26.688,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27,27],[9266,9266,9266,9182.5,9099,9278,9158,9184,9137,9126.5,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116,9116]];
var svg_width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0),
    svg_height = 500;
var svg = d3.select('#svg'),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    chart_width = svg_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    chart_height = svg_height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.attr('width', svg_width).attr('height', svg_height);
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([times[0], times[times.length-1]]).range([0, chart_width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([25.44, 9278]).range([chart_height, 0]);
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(times[i]); })
  .y(yScale)
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
values.forEach(function(curve, i) {
  var line = lineGenerator(curve);
  g.append('path').attr('d', line).attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

However, sometimes data will be `null`. In this case I want to leave gaps in the curve as illustrated in this [tutorial](http://d3indepth.com/shapes/) (search for "Suppose our data has a gap in it" to find the exact spot in the tutorial). The tutorial as well as other examples online show that this can be done with `lineGenerator.defined(function(d) { return d !== null; });`. However, this isn't working:

```js
'use strict';
var times = [new Date(1511589600000),new Date(1511589660000),new Date(1511589720000),new Date(1511589780000),new Date(1511589840000),new Date(1511589900000),new Date(1511589960000),new Date(1511590020000),new Date(1511590080000),new Date(1511590140000),new Date(1511590200000),new Date(1511590260000),new Date(1511590320000),new Date(1511590380000),new Date(1511590440000),new Date(1511590500000),new Date(1511590560000),new Date(1511590620000),new Date(1511590680000),new Date(1511590740000),new Date(1511590800000),new Date(1511590860000),new Date(1511590920000),new Date(1511590980000),new Date(1511591040000),new Date(1511591100000),new Date(1511591160000),new Date(1511591220000),new Date(1511591280000),new Date(1511591340000),new Date(1511591400000),new Date(1511591460000),new Date(1511591520000),new Date(1511591580000),new Date(1511591640000),new Date(1511591700000),new Date(1511591760000),new Date(1511591820000),new Date(1511591880000),new Date(1511591940000),new Date(1511592000000),new Date(1511592060000),new Date(1511592120000),new Date(1511592180000),new Date(1511592240000),new Date(1511592300000),new Date(1511592360000),new Date(1511592420000),new Date(1511592480000),new Date(1511592540000),new Date(1511592600000),new Date(1511592660000),new Date(1511592720000),new Date(1511592780000),new Date(1511592840000),new Date(1511592900000),new Date(1511592960000),new Date(1511593020000),new Date(1511593080000),new Date(1511593140000),new Date(1511593200000)];
var values = [[null,null,null,null,null,25.44,25.752,28.8,26.376,27.6,27,26.4,25.8,25.2,24.6,24,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,9266,9182.5,9099,9278,9158,9527,8840,9126.5,9116,8841.5,8842,8842.5,8843,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]];
var svg_width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0),
    svg_height = 500;
var svg = d3.select('#svg'),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    chart_width = svg_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    chart_height = svg_height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.attr('width', svg_width).attr('height', svg_height);
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([times[0], times[times.length-1]]).range([0, chart_width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([, 9527]).range([chart_height, 0]);
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .defined(function(d) { return d !== null; })
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(times[i]); })
  .y(yScale)
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
values.forEach(function(curve, i) {
  var line = lineGenerator(curve);
  g.append('path').attr('d', line).attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

What did I do wrong? The only difference between the first and second block of code is that the second block has some `null` values and the `.defined(function(d) { return d !== null; })` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `yScale` domain is not correct. Right now it is:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([, 9527])
//no number here ---------------------^
```

It has to be an array of two values, like this:

```
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 9527])
```

Here is the working code:

```js
'use strict';
var times = [new Date(1511589600000),new Date(1511589660000),new Date(1511589720000),new Date(1511589780000),new Date(1511589840000),new Date(1511589900000),new Date(1511589960000),new Date(1511590020000),new Date(1511590080000),new Date(1511590140000),new Date(1511590200000),new Date(1511590260000),new Date(1511590320000),new Date(1511590380000),new Date(1511590440000),new Date(1511590500000),new Date(1511590560000),new Date(1511590620000),new Date(1511590680000),new Date(1511590740000),new Date(1511590800000),new Date(1511590860000),new Date(1511590920000),new Date(1511590980000),new Date(1511591040000),new Date(1511591100000),new Date(1511591160000),new Date(1511591220000),new Date(1511591280000),new Date(1511591340000),new Date(1511591400000),new Date(1511591460000),new Date(1511591520000),new Date(1511591580000),new Date(1511591640000),new Date(1511591700000),new Date(1511591760000),new Date(1511591820000),new Date(1511591880000),new Date(1511591940000),new Date(1511592000000),new Date(1511592060000),new Date(1511592120000),new Date(1511592180000),new Date(1511592240000),new Date(1511592300000),new Date(1511592360000),new Date(1511592420000),new Date(1511592480000),new Date(1511592540000),new Date(1511592600000),new Date(1511592660000),new Date(1511592720000),new Date(1511592780000),new Date(1511592840000),new Date(1511592900000),new Date(1511592960000),new Date(1511593020000),new Date(1511593080000),new Date(1511593140000),new Date(1511593200000)];
var values = [[null,null,null,null,null,25.44,25.752,28.8,26.376,27.6,27,26.4,25.8,25.2,24.6,24,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[null,null,9266,9182.5,9099,9278,9158,9527,8840,9126.5,9116,8841.5,8842,8842.5,8843,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]];
var svg_width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0),
    svg_height = 500;
var svg = d3.select('#svg'),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    chart_width = svg_width - margin.left - margin.right,
    chart_height = svg_height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
svg.attr('width', svg_width).attr('height', svg_height);
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([times[0], times[times.length-1]]).range([0, chart_width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 9527]).range([chart_height, 0]);
var lineGenerator = d3.line()
  .defined(function(d) { return d !== null; })
  .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(times[i]); })
  .y(yScale)
  .curve(d3.curveCardinal);
values.forEach(function(curve, i) {
  var line = lineGenerator(curve);
  g.append('path').attr('d', line).attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);
});
```

```html
<svg id="svg"></svg>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

PS: as you can see, your claim (*"The only difference between the first and second block of code is..."*) was not correct. You can use an online diff checker, as [this one](https://www.diffchecker.com/), to catch those minor changes. Also, most good code editors have a diff tool.

Comment: Yikes, didn't see that, the number was being improperly printed by PHP